# How to select a listview in espresso?

Tags: android, listview, testing, android-espresso

I'm testing with espresso and I have multiple AdapterViews in one page, for example, with id: R.id.list1, R.id.list2, when I use

**onData(withMainValue("xx")).check(matches(isDisplayed()))**

```
public static Matcher<Object> withMainValue(final String value) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<Object,
                            GuessYouLikeGoodItem.DataEntity>(GuessYouLikeGoodItem.DataEntity.class) {
        @Override public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("has value " + value);
        }
        @Override public boolean matchesSafely(
                        GuessYouLikeGoodItem.DataEntity item) {
            return item.store_name.contains(value);
        }
    };
}

,
```

the Espresso reports:

```
    android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'is assignable from class: class android.widget.AdapterView' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
    Problem views are marked with '****MATCHES****' below.
```

How to select the specific listview and try onData on it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have multiple listview with unique id, you should be able to check is one of the list is displayed

```
onView(withId(R.id.list1)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

If you want to go inside AdapterView, this will allow you to click an element inside listview

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list1)).atPosition(0).perform(click());
```

Comment: Thanks! the anything() saved me.

Comment: To use `anything()` you need to have that import: `import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.anything;`.

Comment: with anything() my test never proceeds after showing "Started running tests" in "log". You know why?

Comment: Is there any way to click ListView base on search text?